# Android Studio Project require older version of Gradle

Tags: android, qt, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to compile some Android Studio Project, but get this error message:

```
Gradle sync failed: Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 3.3.
```

When I click to `fix issue` link near the message, I'm getting:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find property 'androidCompileSdkVersion' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@580ec9dd.
```

In file 'android-build' I have:

```
/*******************************************************
 * The following variables:
 * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
 * - androidCompileSdkVersion
 * - qt5AndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
 *                   needed to build any Qt application
 *                   on Android.
 *
 * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
 * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
 * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
 *******************************************************/

compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
        aidl.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
        res.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion and gradle version set in the build.gradle file??

Comment: Hm, so, I viewing 'gradle-wrapper.properties' and have not such variables, and in the 'build.gradle' they are absent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the gradle version at your project root build.gradle file like below

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Or change it to the latest gradle version which you have upgraded to.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with Qt 5.11.1, the easiest fix was to just copy the gradle.properties file from the android build directory to sit next to build.gradle.

I found it here:

build-MyApp-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_11_1_for_Android_armv7-Release/android-build/gradle.properties

Once copied in, Android Studio was able to sync. Make sure not to commit this file! You'll need to copy another one if you upgrade Qt.